# No devuelve el valor del IDENTITY proveniente de un insert en Stored Procedure en Windows Forms

Tags: windows-forms, identity, sql-server-2016

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado que graba encabezado y detalle de una factura desde Windows Forms en C#.  Lo que necesito es poder obtener el enc_id (que es IDENTITY) que ya lo logré asignar al detalle en el procedimiento almacenado y que lo pongo como parámetro OUTPUT. Necesito obtenerlo con Windows Forms c# para usarlo en la generación de la factura.  He aquí mi código:

```
CREATE OR ALTER procedure [dbo].[spr_guarda_factura]
 @enc_fecha_grabado             DateTime
,@enc_fecha_docto               DateTime
,@enc_numero_autorizacion       varchar(64)
,@enc_serie_docto               varchar(32)
,@enc_numero_docto              varchar(32)
,@cli_id                        int
,@enc_nombres_cliente           varchar(128)
,@enc_apellidos_cliente         varchar(128)
,@cli_nit                       varchar(16)
,@tdo_id                        int
,@pve_id                        int
,@enc_fecha_primer_pago         datetime
,@enc_monto_enganche            numeric(12,2)
,@enc_numero_cuotas             int
,@enc_monto_total               numeric(12,2)
,@enc_valor_descuento           numeric(13,2)
,@enc_direccion_cliente         varchar(256)
,@detalle                       factura_det_type READONLY
,@enc_id                        int OUTPUT
```

El último parámetro que pongo es el @enc_id  int OUTPUT-

Luego inserto encabezado

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @enc_xml                xml

    -- Inserta encabezado de factura
    INSERT INTO inv_documento_enc
        ( enc_fecha_grabado
         ,enc_fecha_docto
         ,enc_numero_autorizacion
         ,enc_serie_docto
         ,enc_numero_docto
         ,cli_id
         ,enc_nombres_cliente
         ,enc_apellidos_cliente
         ,cli_nit
         ,tdo_id
         ,pve_id
         ,enc_fecha_primer_pago
         ,enc_monto_enganche
         ,enc_numero_cuotas
         ,enc_monto_total
         ,enc_valor_descuento
         ,enc_direccion_cliente
        )
        VALUES
        (
          @enc_fecha_grabado
         ,@enc_fecha_docto
         ,@enc_numero_autorizacion
         ,@enc_serie_docto
         ,@enc_numero_docto
         ,@cli_id
         ,@enc_nombres_cliente
         ,@enc_apellidos_cliente
         ,@cli_nit
         ,@tdo_id
         ,@pve_id
         ,@enc_fecha_primer_pago
         ,@enc_monto_enganche
         ,@enc_numero_cuotas
         ,@enc_monto_total
         ,@enc_valor_descuento
         ,@enc_direccion_cliente
        );
```

Obtengo el valor del IDENTITY del incabezado

```
    SET @enc_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Y con ese valor inserto el detalle, pero ya tengo el valor del encabezado que necesito en Windows Forms c#

Este es mi código en Windows Forms C# con que inserto

```
  using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("spr_guarda_factura", connection);
                var parametroLista = new SqlParameter("@detalle", SqlDbType.Structured);
                SqlParameter p_enc_id = new SqlParameter("@enc_id", SqlDbType.Int);
                parametroLista.TypeName = "factura_det_type";
                parametroLista.Value = dt;
                p_enc_id.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enc_fecha_grabado", enc_fecha_grabado);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enc_fecha_docto", enc_fecha_docto);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enc_numero_autorizacion", enc_numero_autorizacion);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enc_serie_docto", enc_serie_docto);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enc_numero_docto", enc_numero_docto);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cli_id", cli_id);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enc_nombres_cliente", enc_nombres_cliente);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enc_apellidos_cliente", enc_apellidos_cliente);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cli_nit", cli_nit);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tdo_id", tdo_id);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pve_id", pve_id);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enc_fecha_primer_pago", enc_fecha_primer_pago);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enc_monto_enganche", enc_monto_enganche);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enc_numero_cuotas", enc_numero_cuotas);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enc_monto_total", enc_monto_total);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enc_valor_descuento", enc_valor_descuento);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enc_direccion_cliente", enc_direccion_cliente);
                command.Parameters.Add(parametroLista);

                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@enc_id", SqlDbType.VarChar));

                command.Parameters["@enc_id"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                command.Parameters["@enc_id"].Value = "";

                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                string v_enc_id = (string)p_enc_id.Value;
                string valor = command.Parameters["@enc_id"].Value.ToString();
                
                
                connection.Close();
            }
```

Lo debuguie y no sé como recuperar el valor y como usarlo en el formulario principal.

Gracias por su ayuda,

Hola grupo, les quiero comentar que ya me devuelve el valor en la clase en donde estoy insertando, pero ahora necesito utilizar esa variable en el formulario.

Mi código quedó asi:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("spr_guarda_factura", connection);
    var parametroLista = new SqlParameter("@detalle", SqlDbType.Structured);
     parametroLista.TypeName = "factura_det_type";
    parametroLista.Value = dt;
     command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enc_fecha_grabado", enc_fecha_grabado);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enc_fecha_docto", enc_fecha_docto);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enc_numero_autorizacion", enc_numero_autorizacion);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enc_serie_docto", enc_serie_docto);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enc_numero_docto", enc_numero_docto);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cli_id", cli_id);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enc_nombres_cliente", enc_nombres_cliente);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enc_apellidos_cliente", enc_apellidos_cliente);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cli_nit", cli_nit);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tdo_id", tdo_id);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pve_id", pve_id);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enc_fecha_primer_pago", enc_fecha_primer_pago);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enc_monto_enganche", enc_monto_enganche);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enc_numero_cuotas", enc_numero_cuotas);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enc_monto_total", enc_monto_total);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enc_valor_descuento", enc_valor_descuento);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enc_direccion_cliente", enc_direccion_cliente);
    command.Parameters.Add(parametroLista);
     SqlParameter p_enc_id = new SqlParameter("@enc_id", SqlDbType.Int);
     p_enc_id.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    command.Parameters.Add(p_enc_id);
     connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    int valor = Convert.ToInt32(command.Parameters["@enc_id"].Value);
    connection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

en tu procedure debe de devolver SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() y en tu c# debes de realizar  int id= Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

```
   using(SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table(v,vl)  VALUES(@v,@vl);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();",con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v", 'x');
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vl", 'p');
    con.Open();

    int modified = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

    if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) con.Close();
        return modified;
}
```